# Using custom packages on Google-Colaboratory

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, python-packaging

I'm trying to install a custom python package on Google Colaboratory, that is not available on pip. And I'm facing some weird errors while doing that.

For example, here is a boiler-plate python package: https://github.com/mtchavez/python-package-boilerplate.

Then I tried to install it from the source.

```
%%bash
git clone https://github.com/mtchavez/python-package-boilerplate
cd rohan
pip install -e .
```

This time, however, I had experienced errors while importing submodules

```
ImportError: cannot import name ..
```

This package installs perfectly on my local computer/s. So I'm not sure why I'm not able to use it on Colaboratory.

Comment: I had the same issue : you can't use setup.py install to install package on colab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much simpler way to install custom packages on colab:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/mtchavez/python-package-boilerplate
```